# Eclipse PyDev sees undefined variable incorrectly

Tags: python, eclipse, import, pydev

I have a module named `ColorPalette` with the following enumeration in it:

```
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    Black = '#000000'
    White = '#ffffff'
    Purple = '#7e1e9c'
    Green = '#15b01a'
    Blue = '#0343df'
    Pink = '#ff81c0'
    Brown = '#653700'
    Red = '#e50000'
```

In this same module, I can do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print (Color.Yellow.value)
```

And it prints out the hex value of the color I have defined. However, now in another module, when I import this enum and want to define a variable:

```
from ColorPalette import Color
black = Color.Black.value
```

Then the code works (I use the color in a PIL drawing), but Eclipse shows a red underline under the property `value`, with the error `Undefined variable from import: value`.

[image: Red underline]

Do I miss an import, or does PyDev have this wrong? How could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Humm, it seems Enum's are a bit too dynamic to the PyDev type inference engine... Please create a feature request so that I can take a look at this to improve it for this situation (at https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/).

Comment: Thanks. I now created a ticket for this on the Brainwy tracker.

Comment: How's this coming along? I'm still fighting with this problem today using Eclipse Oxygen 3a (4.7.3a) and PyDev for Eclipse 6.4.3.201807050139. I end up having to wrap my enum value in parentheses, like `(Color.Black).value`

Comment: This one is fixed (just tried that exact case here and it worked). If it doesn't work for you, please create a new ticked in the PyDev tracker (https://www.brainwy.com/tracker/PyDev/) with your actual case as it may be different.